# size of a input section GNU ld

Tags: linker, ld

How do you get the size of an input section in ld? I would assume its just `SIZEOF(.section);` however ld gives an error upon trying to run that. Is there any way I can do this? .section would be defined in a .asm file like so

```
section .section
    mov al, 15
```

Here's the linker script I have so far:

```
SECTIONS {
    boot : {
        *( .boot );
        . += SECTOR_SIZE - SIZEOF( .boot_header );
        *( .boot_header );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem with SIZEOF.

Just tested:

```
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >RAM AT> FLASH
  
    _datasize = SIZEOF(.data);
```

Works as expected.

Comment: Sorry I had a miscommunication on my part. I meant a section defined in a file (eg .asm). I adjusted the question accordingly.

Comment: You need to have it defined in the linker script as well. It does not matter what language you use. It can be asm, C, fortran, ADA .....